# Using stringstream precision to format floats but discarding zero-padding

Tags: c++, stringstream

I'm trying to set precision (i.e. number of decimal places) of floats and long doubles to 10, but i don't want them zero padded. I.e.,

123456.789123456789 should give 123456.7891234568, but
123456 should not give 123456.0000000000, but rather 123456

So far i've narrowed it down to:

```
long double myNumber;
string myString;
ostringstream myStream;
myStream.setf(ios::fixed,ios::floatfield);
myStream.precision(10);
myStream << myNumber;
myString = myStream.str();
```

I've also tried fiddling with setfill(' ') and std::ws but can't really get the hang of it.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `ios::fixed` for `ios::floatfield`. That's what causes the padding. Simply use `setprecision`.